# How can I create a table with a column with 3 only possible given values?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm making a SQL database with MySQL.

I need a column that has only 3 possible values: "Total" "Hours" "OnDemmand". I mean that user has to select one of these three values, he will can't select another value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the `ENUM` type.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE sizes (
    name ENUM('small', 'medium', 'large')
);
```

Comment: Note: it's still possible to have an empty value instead of the given three.

Comment: ohh nice! thx..... but...¿how can i create a enum colum with these values on MySQL Workbench (mysql administrator 2010)?

Comment: Just being curious, I don't know mysql, what I have to do If I want to add one more possible value to the column, is it possible to alter the column?

Comment: @johnbk Yes you can alter it like any other column.  Of course you may have an issue if removing a value that is currently used.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can create a check constraint for the column like this -

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
add CONSTRAINT yourcolumn
   CHECK (yourcolumn IN ('Total', 'Hours', 'OnDemand'));
```

There should be equivalent checks incase you are using other database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build it into the table itself you would need to use a check constraint, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
  YourColumn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ck_YourConstraint CHECK (YourColumn = 'Total' OR YourColumn = 'Hours' OR YourColumn = 'OnDemand')
)
```

However, you may want to look into normalizing your database design a step further and putting those into a separate lookup table that your application uses. This will allow you great flexibility in the future in the event that those lookups are modified in any way.

Comment: CHECK CONSTRAINT is allowed syntax in MySQL but is ignored by it. "The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines." from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html